# Yo Yo's robot arms

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

How come when Elena (Yo Yo) used her speed to lock up Mack to get Fitz out of the cell, she was fine, but when she tried to use her speed when they were surrounded, her arms couldn't "keep up" and hurt her

Comment: Wow, you know, I hadn’t noticed that. I can only think the writers forgot.

Comment: Then again, the idea that in however many weeks they just *wouldn’t have tested* her speed left me confused to begin with.

Comment: You could possibly fanwank and say that when the arms malfunctioned was her first time going all-out in a combat situation, previous times only did fairly short low-intensity bursts just to check things seemed okay and the Mac thing which only took a few seconds of motion.

Comment: I can not remember for sure but one of fitz-simmons acknowledges that during the episode after it happens. They mentioned something about needing to re-calibrate something or other due to the electrical signals. If you get a chance to watch the episode again it may become clearer or we might get more details in a future episode when "they" fix it.

Comment: She's actually not fine after she locks Mack up; immediately afterwards she shoots a gun off by accident, and seems surprised by it. So there's the seeds of something wrong there.